# APIConnect JSON array returned from external service issue

Tags: apiconnect, ibm-api-management

We have a Rest API which contains in its assembly only an 'invoke' to an external Rest service without any mapping, such that the API will act only as a gateway.

If the external service is called directly (e.g. through SoapUI), it returns a JSON response which contains an array of objects. The array is nested at a 3 level depth starting from the root object.

Instead, when we call our API with the same request, we get a different response: in the place of the array, we get an object that corresponds to the last object of the array; the other objects of the array are not present in the response.

Is there a way to fix this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Is this on Bluemix or on a dedicated environment? If it is dedicated, can you run the must gather command on your servers to collect the logs and see if anything stands out?

Comment: Hello, are you still having this issue? I have not been able to reproduce it, following the example here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFS6T/com.ibm.apic.toolkit.doc/tutorial_apionprem_apiproxy.html It always pulls all of the items. Maybe your external service is seeing two different sets of request headers and acting differently?